# Is "NOT IN" much slower than <>?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have a rather large query that I recently added a new condition to where I check if a field is not equal to some value. I would have used the not equals condition <> but I wanted to set it up to handle multiple values in case more are added in the future. So to keep the things simple, you can think of the larger query looking like the following smaller query:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE NVL(BAR, 1) NOT IN (2)
```

When I ran the query, it added an additional one minute to my execution time. The original query without this condition returns in a few milliseconds. So I tweaked the condition to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE NVL(BAR, 1) = 1
```

I also tried it out with this

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE NVL(BAR, 1) <> 2
```

And both of these queries return in the desired few milliseconds. But why is using *NOT IN (2)* so much slower than the other approach? It makes no sense to me.

Note: The field bar has a lot of possible null values and the bar column is not indexed.

**UPDATE:**

Okay I just realized I left out a very important detail. This issue was only present when it was run through Java. So I have a String that contains the query and I run it using

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
```

I do not see the issue when I run the query directly on SqlDeveloper.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans for both of them?  Perhaps it's trying to use a bad plan for the `NOT IN`

Comment: What schema is this operating on? What indexes are in place?

Comment: It is not a case of one construction being slower than another, it's that some constructions can limit the optimizer, resulting in a different execution plan. There may be some quirks around this in some versions of Oracle. Presumably the plan is coming out different in your two cases.

Comment: Note that `NVL(x,1) NOT IN (2)` is logically equivalent to `x!=2` (or `x<>2` which is the same), but the latter expression is more likely to use an index on `x` if one exists.

Comment: Show us both execution plans. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

In some case the query optimizer  is not able to manage in efficent way a not in as  left join null or not exist so the full scan and check for match generate a slow query

Assuming you have proper index on BAR column 
you could try avoiding the combination of nvl and not in

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM FOO 
 WHERE BAR NOT IN ( 2 )
 AND BAR IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The bar column is not indexed. I just updated the post to reflect that. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: I just realized I left out an important detail. Please see my update on the question. Sorry.

Comment: I.m not in java framework but use framwork with other language  .. sometimes the framework is not efficent  using active record or others ORM 
 and  is possible  execute   a sqlcommand  ..  directly  .. avoiding framework  .. overhead .. could be this is possible also with your framework ..